# WP7 store purchases not available on surface pro

Tags: apps, store, windows-live

I've purchased games and apps from the market place on my WP7 (HTC Mozart). I've since bought a Surface Pro (Windows 8). When downloading the same apps in W8 I have to repurchase. The store shows no purchase history.

Are WP7 purchases not transferable to W8?

Comment: Pretty sure you can transfer apps between phones but not phone and PC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purchase you made in Windows Phone Store are not the same as the Windows Store.

If you bought an app for Windows Phone 7 and it is available for Windows Phone 8 um don't need to purchase again but with Windows 8 this is not possible.

Some games can implement a mechanism where you don't need to buy in both stores but I only saw this once. It is not a common practice.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for confirming.